# Convert characters (range of temperature) to numbers (lists)

Tags: r, list, class, type-conversion, character

I have a variable in my dataframe (named otemp - class character) that contains ranges of temperatures in °C, and I want to convert the ranges (eg. -55°C ~ 105°C) to numbers (a range with a min and max, eg. -55:105) which I can compare later (greater than, equal to etc.).

Here is the column that contains these values:

```
> head(otemp)  
[1] "-55°C ~ 105°C" "-55°C ~ 105°C" "-55°C ~ 105°C" "-55°C ~ 105°C" "-55°C ~ 125°C" "-55°C ~ 125°C"
```

First, I removed °C:

```
> otemp<- gsub('°C',"",otemp) head(otemp) [1] "-55 ~ 105" "-55 ~ 105"
> "-55 ~ 105" "-55 ~ 105" "-55 ~ 125" "-55 ~ 125"
```

Then I replaced "~" with ":"

```
> otemp <- gsub('~',":",otemp)
> head(otemp) [1] "-55 : 105" "-55 : 105" "-55 : 105" "-55 : 105" "-55 : 125" "-55 : 125"
```

How can I convert from the current class (character) to a range of numbers? (eg. -55:105 as a range will result in a range of numbers from -55 to 105)

Comment: Assuming that you want to separate the values for min and max into two different columns, I'd prefer ```tidyr::separate(otemp, c("min", "max"),  " : ")```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(unlist( str_extract_all(otemp, "[0-9.]+")))
#[1]  55 105  55 105  55 105  55 105  55 125  55 125
```

---

Or with `gregexpr/regmatches` from `base R`

```
as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(otemp, gregexpr("[0-9.]+", otemp))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @akrun! I have tried str_extract_all with as numeric, but I would like it to be a range from 55 to 105 (55:105). The above result gives me two separate values that cannot be understood as a range, and it won't allow me to perform my comparisions...

Comment: @Kathia In that case  `unlist(sapply(str_extract_all(otemp, "[0-9.]+"), function(x) Reduce(":", as.numeric(x))))`  If you don't need a single vector, keep it as a `list` with `lapply(str_extract_all`

Comment: the first one is good because I want to keep the column as vector with class numeric. Do you think there is any possibility to obtain a range written like this:  55:105,  55:105,  55:105,  55:105,  55:125,  55:125?
I have tried this: eval(parse(text = paste("c(", gsub("\\~", ":", otemp), ")")))
but it shows all the numbers between 55 and 105 instead of just writing it in a form of a range of numbers: 55:105

Comment: @Kathia You can paste it with `sapply(str_extract_all(otemp, "[0-9.]+"), paste, collapse=":")` but then you have to do `sapply(res, function(x) eval(parse(text= x)))`  It is not the approach I would recommend

Comment: @akrun - Upvoted because I agree with you that it shouldn't have been downvoted

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clumsy, but very transparent way of doing this. Remove degrees Celsius, split by tilde, coerce to numeric matrix. Happy dance

```
x <- c("-55°C ~ 105°C", "-55°C ~ 105°C", "-55°C ~ 105°C", "-55°C ~ 105°C", "-55°C ~ 125°C", "-55°C ~ 125°C")
x <- gsub("°C", "", x)
x <- strsplit(x, "~")
x <- sapply(x, as.numeric)
t(x)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  -55  105
[2,]  -55  105
[3,]  -55  105
[4,]  -55  105
[5,]  -55  125
[6,]  -55  125
```

Comment: @ Yes I've tried something similar that resulted in two columns: d[,c("otmin","otmax")]<-as.numeric(do.call("rbind",strsplit(otemp,split = ":"))) but I would like to do it within the same column

Comment: Please edit your question to show how the desired output should look like. String `-55 : 105` is not usable in R (but you may have other applications).